# How to send a SOAP message through a proxy that needs authentication?

Tags: java, soap, proxy

I'm writing a servlet in java 1.7 hosted in Apache Tomcat 7, and I'm trying to send a SOAP 1.2 message to a web service. Not a very challenging feature, so I wrote this little bit of code to do it:

```
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    String url = petition.getUrl();
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(xml), url);
```

The problem is that my company proxy is stopping the call and I'm always getting a Timeout Exception. I've found that I can set proxy settings like this, but it doesn't include a way to introduce the proxy authentication I need to complete the call.

```
//Set the http proxy to webcache.example.com:8080
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.example.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Is there a way to log me in the proxy without having to use URLConnection to send the SOAP message?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Jax-ws client with basic authentication , the following code set the authentication config without using URLConnection :

```
Service s = new Service();
Port port = s.getPort();

BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myusername");
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");

port.call();
```

Comment: how does this goes, could you provide an example for it